# Can Intellij / Android Studio fold comments?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I have this commented out piece of code in intellij:

[image]

As you can see, there is no possibility to fold comments here. However, the same commented block in Webstorm can be collapse:

[image]

Is there any way to configure comments collapsing in intellij/Android Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**
It is a know bug, which can be found in JetBrains Bug Tracking System - [IDEA-106702](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106702). It only affects block comments (/* comment */), all other comments are treated correctly.

**General Editor folding settings**

You can configure code folding in Settings (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
 - Editor  → General  → Code Folding

Here you can toggle folding outline and also configure default folding behavior for various file sections such as comments, imports, xml tags and more.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and it still didn't work. As you can see from the pictures in my question these are not documentation comments, but regular block comments as I understand it.

Comment: Jus tested it and strangely enough - idea will show folds when you use single line comments to comment out a block of code but not when using block comments as you do.

Answer (score 13):

To fold an arbitrary selected block

1. Select contiguous fragment of code in the editor.
2. On the main menu, choose Code|Folding|Fold Selection/Remove Region, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd>

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/folding-and-expanding-custom-blocks.html

Comment: Thanks, although it's not about folding comments, it's still very useful and can be used as a workaround until the bug is resolved. I upvoted.

Comment: Most definitely folds comment block!

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.0
Firstly put cursor on a code block that you want to fold/collapse and Hit

> **`Ctrl` + `NumPad`-`**

Answer (score 0):

It took 4 years, but the team behind Intellij IDEA managed to solve this problem! This is the first version where the bug is solved:

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Community Edition)

Build #IC-191.6183.87, built on March 27, 2019

JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b39 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 10.0