# How to fold block comments in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm referencing to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026049/can-intellij-android-studio-fold-comments/32317900) question dated May 4th 2015, where the absence of a way to fold block comments is described as a known bug in the accepted answer.

**Now, in late 2018, do they resolved this bug?**

I find it very annoying, especially when I have to test some methods. 
Moreover I think it would be quite easy for JetBrains to add this feature/solve this bug!

Comment: This is in the same status. The [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106702) is not resolved yet.

Comment: Folding works for Javadoc. Can you make it a Javadoc block instead?

Comment: @lealceldeiro is there a way to highlight that bug report? Or should I open another one? Thanks

Comment: @PeterLawrey indeed, this confirms it is a bug. It's strange they didn't resolved this in newer versions, since they know this bug... By the way thanks, I'll use this workaround

Comment: @MarcoRossi I have no idea how to highlight this. You should probably open a new one because this hasn't been updated in **2** years (according to the info shown in the issue link).

Comment: @lealceldeiro I've added a comment and mentioned the 'assignee' of the [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106702). I doubt they will answer me, but there's no harm in trying. Tbh I really don't understand why they don't resolve this. I'm not an experienced programmer at all, but I find comment folding an useful feature, especially when you are building your program and you have to remember a lot of things, but you don't want your classes to be a mess. Moreover, as I said, I think it would be an easy fix since they implemented it for Javadoc comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 years later the [first reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026049/can-intellij-android-studio-fold-comments/55424821#55424821) of this bug, the team which works on Intellij IDEA managed to solve this problem!

[image: As you can see "-" placeholders now appears]

---

This is the first version where the bug is solved:

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Community Edition)

Build #IC-191.6183.87, built on March 27, 2019

JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b39 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 1):

If you add another asterisk to the comment block start, then you will be able to fold the multi line comment. It's a workaround, but it's fast and easy.

Before:

[image]

After

[image]

After code formatting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I know this, indeed I can fold Javadoc comments. However this is still a workaround, they didn't resolved the bug. By the way thank you, I'll use this for now